# FIle created is not valid/Invalid file

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, filesystems, file-type

I am creating a blank file(.xlsx) on user's desktop, then I need to open the file and to fill this file with data, but while opening the file I am getting an error "file is invalid". I am using below code:

```
Dim filePath As String = desktopPath & "\Suspense_" & Now.Date.ToString("MMddyy") & ".xlsx"

Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
fs = File.Create(filePath)
'getting error on below line
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
```

While the file is created successfully, it fails to open.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just creating a file with XLSX extension doesn't mean that you have created a valid Excel file. You need to use Excel itself (Interop libraries) or some thirdy party libraries (EPPlus)  that know how an empty Excel file is formatted

Answer (score 0):

Creating a file and renaming the extension does not mean it is a file of that type. Just like renaming a .png file to .txt does not mean it is now a text file.

To create a blank Excel file:

Add a reference to `Microsoft Excel Object Library` (which ever version you have installed on your machine)

Then use this code to create a blank xlsx file:

```
Private _xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Private _xlWSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Private _xlWBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

Public Sub CreateNewFile()
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Scratch\Test1.xlsx"
    _xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    _xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    _xlWBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    _xlWBook.SaveAs(filename)
    CloseAndCleanUpExcelObjects()
End Sub

Private Sub CloseAndCleanUpExcelObjects()
    'close the workbook and quit the app
    If _xlWBook IsNot Nothing Then _xlWBook.Close()
    If _xlApp IsNot Nothing Then _xlApp.Quit()
    'destroy the objects
    If _xlWSheet IsNot Nothing Then _xlWSheet = Nothing
    If _xlWBook IsNot Nothing Then _xlWBook = Nothing
    If _xlApp IsNot Nothing Then _xlApp = Nothing

    'Force garbage collection
    GC.Collect()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!! I was using the reference before also, but still getting the error on   xlWorkSheet.Cells( 1, "C") = "2" assigning the value.